# Marking locations (Latitude, Longitude) on Google Map from SQLite Database

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sqlite

I am trying to mark locations on Google Map from SQLite Database on Android Studio.can anyone give suggestion for retrieving location from SQLite Database then Marking these location on Google Map.

Answer (score 0):

Implement *OnMapReadyCallback* in your activity and in *onMapReady* callback set the marker.

**Eg:**

```
  public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //for setting custom marker
        Drawable circleDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_placeholder);
        BitmapDescriptor icon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable);

        //create LatLng object using value got from sqlite db
        LatLng selectedPlace = new LatLng(mLat, mLong);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(selectedPlace).title(mName).icon(icon));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(selectedPlace, 10));
    }

}
```

**Note:** You need to add the play-service-map dependency in build.gradle of app module

Comment: Thank you.But  i have list of  latitude and longitude with name in SQLite Database. now i want to show them on google map. please help me

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my answer. It works successfully:

```
public void show(View view) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "select lat,lng from places", null );
    String []latitude=new String[3];
    String []longitude=new String[3];
    double []dlatitude= new double[3];
    double []dlongitude= new double[3];

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            latitude[i]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( "lat" ));
            dlatitude[i]=Double.parseDouble( latitude[i] );

            longitude[i]=cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "lng" ) );
            dlongitude[i]=Double.parseDouble( longitude[i] );
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<latitude.length;j++) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng( dlatitude[j], dlongitude[j] );
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position( latLng );
        markerOptions.title( "current location" );
        mMap.addMarker( markerOptions );
        mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng( latLng ) );
        markerOptions.draggable( true );
    }
}
```